# vermelho/negativo e verde/positivo

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Tenho uma tabela que, hora o valor é negativo e, hora é positivo. Gostaria que esse valores ficassem verdes ou vermelhos. Mas, não consegui fazer isso. Atualmente meu select esta sendo apresentado dessa maneira:

```
(php, myadmin, pdo)


<?php
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT sum(premio) as premio from home 
WHERE id_user = :id_user;");
        $sql->bindValue(":id_user", $id);
        $sql->execute();

        if ($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
            foreach ($sql->fetchAll() as $item) {
        ?>
     <tr>
        <th>Ganho</th>
        <td> R$ <?php echo $item['premio'];?></td>
     </tr>
     <?php
        }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo Gabriel Alves ao Stack Overflow em Português. Cãso nã fazer um tour pelo sita em o tenha feito seria interessante https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use uma condicional para setar um estilo a `td` verificando o valor de `$item['premio']`

```
<?php
      $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT sum(premio) as premio from home WHERE id_user = :id_user;");
        $sql->bindValue(":id_user", $id);
        $sql->execute();

        if ($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
            foreach ($sql->fetchAll() as $item) {

            //valor
            $premio = $item['premio'];

                //condicional
                if ($premio<0){
                    $cor='red';
                }else{
                    $cor='green';
                }
?>
     <tr>
        <th>Ganho</th>
        <td style='color:<?php echo $cor;?>'> R$ <?php echo $premio;?></td>
     </tr>
<?php
   }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Leo muito obrigado, foi muito mais simples que imaginei e alcançou exatamente o objetivo. Ultima coisa, na minha tela rome terá muitos resultados , você acha uma ma pratica fazer isso dessa forma, (separadamente para cada resultado) MAS JA VLW MUITO OBRIGADO.

Comment: @GabrielAlves, não acho uma má pratica, não tem como não aplicar separadamente para cada resultado mesmo que seja com class css